# Getting the warning from chrome dev tools that each child should have a unique key prop

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning `Reactjs` and tried to copy the example from this [facebook git](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-), children to make the warning disappear, but I'm still getting it:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function () {
    return {idx: 0};
  },

  render: function() {
    var results = this.props.results;
    return (
      <ol>
        {results.map(function(result) {
          return <li key={result.id}>{result.book}</li>;
        })}
      </ol>
    );
  }

});

var result = [
  {title: "book", content: "booky"},
  {title: "pen", content: "penny"},
];

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent results={results} />, document.getElementById('widgets'));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things going on here that need to be rectified:

The variable you're declaring and assigning the array of results to is named `result` but you are passing a variable named `results` as the results prop to `MyComponent`. Rename this variable to `results`.

The two object properties you're attempting to access on the `result` object inside the map function are `id` and `book`, neither of which are defined on the object itself (`title` and `content` are). Change `{result.book}` to `{result.title}` in this case.

Finally, in order to supply a unique ID to each element returned from the map, set the second parameter of your map (e.g. `results.map(function(result, i) {...` and use the array index as your unique key.

In summary:

```
results.map(function(result, i) {
  return <li key={i}>{result.title}</li>;
})
```

Comment: THANK YOU @Rick !!! the first two mistakes were due to me copying and pasting stuff, but getting the index from the map was just what i needed! thanks!!